# specifc keydown to trigger an event

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use a specific key to trigger an event within my page.

here is my js

```
$(".ryu").keydown(function() {
        $(".ryu-still").hide();
        $(".ryu-cool").show();
    });
```

any idea on how to trigger the event using the "X" key

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    $('.ryu"').bind('keydown', function(e) {


            if(e.keyCode== "x"){
              //do something
             $(".ryu-still").hide();
             $(".ryu-cool").show();
         }

        });
```

good luck

Answer (score 1):

you need to catch to see if the key being pressed is the right one

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".ryu").on('keydown',function(e){   
      if(e.which==88){ //88 = x key
          $(".ryu-still").hide();
          $(".ryu-cool").show(); 
      }

   });    
});
```

jsfiddle or it didnt happen
http://jsfiddle.net/u3uo7eLn/2/